# google location API failed after publishing my android app

Tags: android, google-location-services

when i was using google location API in my android app , it was working fine but after publishing it on playstore it says API_KEY_FAILED.

After google, I found that I need to put my SHA1 Fingerprint key and restrict the API, but after doing so still it is not working.

I did with the release(live) keystore.

Comment: You created live api key using your live keystore and not debug.keystore? Just tell me using which keystore you have created google map api key.

Comment: i did with the release(live) keystore

Comment: Then it should work. Some problem in your key generation only. Can you please paste the command using which you have created key?